# Visual studio winform designer shows design errors as text rather than html

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS2005 Winforms Designer Exception Screen and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761155/vs2005-winforms-designer-exception-screen-and-ie8)

All of the sudden, visual studio displays designer errors as plain html text, for example:

> `<DIV id="div1" class="ErrorStyle" width="100%"><span style="font-weight: 600"><br>Object reference not set to an instance of an object. </span><br><a href=""`

instead of displaying the usual html formatted. I haven't been able to find anything similar to it on google.

Before getting this problem, when I tried opening the winform designer, I would get the run/save/cancel dialog of internet explorer for a .tmp file, instead of the designer window. That went away when I found out that I had notepad assigned to the .tmp file type and removed that.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick workaround is to modify the registry settings.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes
```

Add a key called `.tmp` to this.

Then, add the following strings:

```
(Default)     REG_SZ    htmlfile
Content Type  REG_SZ    text/html
PerceivedType REG_SZ    text
```

And that should do it.

Comment: I like how you post the response after I showed you how to fix it!

Comment: Awesome! it solved the problem indeed. I'd never have thought it'd be related to IE8.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to IE8.  Others with this problem have been able to fix it by reverting to IE7.  I have not tried that my self.

- [VS2005 Winforms Designer Exception Screen and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761155/vs2005-winforms-designer-exception-screen-and-ie8)
- [VS2005 with WinXP: Designer's Error Page shows html Code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdesigner/thread/5fb244e0-017f-4387-8567-ab134089bb81)

**EDIT**: I've posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761155/vs2005-winforms-designer-exception-screen-and-ie8/3015130#3015130) on a duplicate stackoverflow question.